# inject html using ajax

Tags: html, ajax, haml

I have a HAML page with some div elements. I need to inject this into a div on another page when a button is clicked. how do i do this? thanks

Comment: what technology do you want to use? javascript and python?

Comment: ajax/javascript...using rails (mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the jQuery plugin from jQuery.com. you can download the plugin or use the link 
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js as src in the js file.

then use the follwing code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#your_button_Id").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      context: document.body,
      success: function(response){
        $('#div_Id').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!!!
happy coding.

Comment: when i use this code, it loads the header/footer etc, instead of just whats in my html file (i.e. only the divs). The html file doesnt have any header/footer etc....any ideas?

Comment: @newbie_86 What Web framework are you using with your Haml? (Sinatra, Rails, ...?) You need to turn off your layout for the request, or use a partial with just that Haml template.

Comment: You can actually send the response from the server like what ever you want instead of sending the complete html.

Answer (score 0):

try $('div').load('lol.HTML') if you want to use jquery

Answer (score 0):

To simplify this process, add the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) to your page.

Below is an example of using jQuery to load data from a different page into the current page:

```
inject_to = $("div#id"); // the div to load the html into
load_from = "/some/other/page"; // the url to the page to load html from
data = ""; // optional data to send to the other page when loading it

// do an asynchronous GET request
$.get(load_from, data, function(data)
{
    // put the received html into the div
    inject_to.html(data);
}
```

Note that this opens for security/xss issues, and I would recommend using .text instead of .html, and load only plain text from the external page. More info on jQuery ajax: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

To do this when a button is clicked, put the above code into a function, like this:

```
function buttonClicked()
{
    inject_to = $("div#id"); // the div to load the html into
    load_from = "/some/other/page"; // the url to the page to load html from
    data = ""; // optional data to send to the other page when loading it

    // do an asynchronous GET request
    $.get(load_from, data, function(data)
    {
        // put the received html into the div
        inject_to.html(data);
    }
}
```

Then add an event handler for the click event to the button, like this:

```
$("button#id").click(buttonClicked);
```

More info on jQuery events: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: when injecting, how do i get it to overwrite the contents of that div with the injected content?

Comment: When using the .html function it will always overwrite the content.

Comment: it isn't overwriting it for me....just seems to add what was there before beneath the injected content

Comment: i have this in my haml #myDiv= @lineItems.last.my_field.to_s.html_safe   and the ajax as follows:$.ajax({
            url: "myTestUrl",
            context: document.body,
            success: function(response){
                $('#myDiv').html(response);
            }
        });

Comment: That's weird, could you post the html as well, after it is processed by haml? Perhaps haml is making malformed html.

Comment: ok, i got it to work. there was an odd p tag interfering with the layout. how would i go about injecting content in this same div, when a button is clicked? what i'm trying to achieve is sort of like a wizard, i click a button on step 1 and the content is replaced with step 2, i click a button on step 2 and i get step 3. all steps are separate html pages, how can i do this generically? thanks

Comment: Added more info in the answer.

Comment: but what if your button is in the html page you've just injected, where would you bind the click event since button#id doesn't exist in the dom on initial load and when you inject, it isn't a reload...

Comment: You'd have to bind the .click event when the html is injected then.